# Fill iOS Tabbar icon with different color

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller

How can i fill iOS TabBar icon with different color when selected and deselected or can i have different image for each of the state? 
 [image]

EDIT: I want the border effect where some will have border and transparent background while some will be filled

Comment: It's your problem. The system shows the provided image or images only. You should create an image or images for both states respectively. For example: *exampleSelected.png* and *exampleUnselected.png*. They are should be different.

Comment: How can i show different images for the selected and unselected state @Mannopson

Answer (score 0):

You can set UITabBar icon's colour when it is selected:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:<YOUR-COLOR>];
```

Comment: Yes but that will change the color of the image and the i want the border effect where some will have border and transparent background while some will be filled